# Duplicate prevention and Merge on Account

Tags: apex, externalid, duplicate-management, jitterbit

We have an integration with a legacy system and we use an Unique ExternalID  to send personAccount upserts back and forth between salesforce and the legacy system using JItterbit.
However, that externalID is provided by the legacy system, When a new record is created in Salesforce it is sent to the legacy system where it gets the Unique ExternalID. 
Problem is on the way back to Salesforce since the ExternalID isn't already on the Account, Jitterbit creates a new duplicate account.

Anyone have any thoughts on how we can get the ExternalID field populated on the existing account?